# recyclerview hide/show based on boolean with multiple view types

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 3 viewtypes to be shown in a recyclerview.

```
--------view type 1 ----------
--------view type 2 ----------
--------view type 2 ----------
--------view type 3 ----------
--------view type 3 ----------
--------view type 3 ----------
--------view type 3 ----------
--------view type 3 ----------
```

View type 1 is a single instance where viewtype 2 & 3 can be unknow number of multiple instances

Now when i click viewtype 1 i want to toggle hide/show all the instances of viewtype 2

For that I am trying the following:

define a boolean variable in the main recyclerview adapter class

```
private boolean mShowsView;
```

Then using onclick on viewtype1 i change it to true or false

```
@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardviewsearchsuggested, parent, false);
    SearchSuggestRVAdapter.PersonViewHolder viewHolder = new SearchSuggestRVAdapter.PersonViewHolder(v);
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(mShowsView){
            mShowsView = false;
        }
        else{
            mShowsView = true;
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    return pvh;
}
```

Then i also put condition for viewtype2: in the onCreateviewholder

```
View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardviewsearchsuggested, parent, false);
viewHolder = new PersonViewHolderSuggested(v1);
if(!mShowsView){
    viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else{
    viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewHolder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
}
```

After clicking the viewtype1 mShowsView value toggles but it does not refresh the viewtype2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put any changes you want to make in `onBindViewHolder()` and not `onCreateViewHolder()`, since `onCreateViewHolder()` is called only when a new ViewHolder is created, and `onBindViewHolder()` is called whenever data changes. You can force-call `onCreateViewHolder()` by messing with the view-type, but this is the simplest solution.